# How to test django caching?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache

Is there a way to be **sure** that a page is coming from cache on a production server and on the development server as well?

The solution **shouldn't** involve caching middleware because not every project uses them. Though the solution itself might **be** a middleware.

Just checking if the data is stale is not a very safe testing method IMO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We do a lot of component caching and not all of them are updated at the same time. So we set host and timestamp values in a universally included context processor. At the top of each template fragment we stick in:

```
<!-- component_name {{host}} {{timestamp}} -->
```

The component_name just makes it easy to do a View Source and search for that string.

All of our views that are object-detail pages define a context variable "page_object" and we have this at the top of the base.html template master:

```
<!-- {{page_object.class_id}} @ {{timestamp}} -->
```

class_id() is a method from a super class used by all of our primary content classes. It is just:

```
def class_id(self):
    "%s.%s.%s" % (self.__class__._meta.app_label,
                    self.__class__.__name__, self.id)
```

If you load a page and any of the timestamps are more than few seconds old, it's a pretty good bet that the component was cached.

Comment: Elegant solution. Can be automated as well. Thanks.

Comment: Just for convenience sake, do you have the context processors you mentioned somewhere on djangosnippets.org or other site?

Comment: Adding a context processor is easy!
1. Create a file, e.g. my_context.py.
2. Create a function that takes a request object, e.g. my_context(request).
3. Return a dict of fun stuff available to all templates.
4. Add "my_context.my_context" to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py.
5. Profit!

Answer (score 16):

Peter Rowells suggestion works well, but you don't need a custom template context processor 
for timestamps. You can simply use the template tag:

```
 <!-- {% now "jS F Y H:i" %} -->
```

Comment: FWIW this broke the styling of my site in IE8 very badly when I added it as the first line of my template. Seems to be fine when it's inside the html tags. And I put it in html comment tags. Took a long time to figure out that was the cause of my css problems.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I'm afraid, I forgot about the comment tags. I fixed my solution entry accordingly.

Comment: it just needs to be inside the <html> declaration. just thought I'd post for future people reading this thread. but thanks, it is a simple and effective solution

Answer (score 8):

Mock the view, hit the page, and see if the mock was called. if it was not, the cache was used instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you use caches is to improve performance.  Test the performance by running a load test against your server.  If the server's performance matches your needs, then you are all set!